# Text in table cells isn't in the center

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Question: Here i am working with a simple table in which i am finding that some text are not centrally(vertically) align. How can i solve this issue?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,headheight=14.5pt,]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Question           & Answer                \\ \hline
    $1$                & $A$                  \\\hline
    $2$                & $B$                  \\\hline
    $3$                & $C$                  \\\hline
    $4$                & $D$                 \\\hline
    $5$                & $A$                 \\\hline
    $6$                & $B$                 \\\hline
    $7$                & $D$                 \\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try add some extra row height: `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` (for example after `\beginbcenter}` or if you wish in document preamble).

Comment: @Zarko Would you please correct my code? its my humble request.

Comment: Could you please explain why all the numbers and the letters anre in math mode? This is most likely not needed here.

Comment: @leandriis it was done by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            vmargin=1in, hmargin.7in,
            headheight=14.5pt,]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} load by article
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % load msmath
\usepackage{amssymb}    % load amsfonts
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    Question           & Answer             \\ \hline
    $1$                & $A$                \\\hline
    $2$                & $B$                \\\hline
    $3$                & $C$                \\\hline
    $4$                & $D$                \\\hline
    $5$                & $A$                \\\hline
    $6$                & $B$                \\\hline
    $7$                & $D$                \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, if you will use in text letters as g, y, j, f, than will vertical center will optically looks different. With other words, text is now already vertical centered if you consider mentioned letters.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are using **c** as column definition which does not support line breaks. That means the rows height will not exceed one line and so vertical alignment is neglectable.

In case of using fixed column widths with p{...} which supports line breaks this issue can be solved by using the *array* packe and **m{...}** for column definition.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,headheight=14.5pt,]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|m{3cm}|}
    \hline
    Question           & Answer                             \\ \hline
    question           & answer answer answer answer answer \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result (top without vertical centering, bottom with vertical centering) :[image]